# Reg Expression to reduce huge file size?

Tags: json, regex, vba, extract, large-data

I have a series of *gigantic* (40-80mb) exported Google Location History `JSON` files, with which I've been tasked to analyze select activity data.  Unfortunately Google has no parameter or option at their [download site](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/location_history) to choose anything except *"one giant JSON containing **forever***".  (The `KML` option is twice as big.)

Obvious choices like [`JSON-Converter` (laexcel-test incarnation of `VBA-JSON`)](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/releases); parsing line-by line with VBA; even [Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).  They all *crash and burn*.  I'm thinking *RegEx* might be the answer.

1. [This Python script](https://github.com/Scarygami/location-history-json-converter) can extract the timestamp and location from a 40mb file in two seconds (with RegEx?).  **How is Python doing it so fast?** (Would it be as fast in VBA?)
2. I'd be able to extract everything I need, piece by piece, if only I had a magic chunk of `RegEx`, perhaps with this logic:

   - **Delete everything** *except:*
     When `timestampMs` and  `WALKING` appear between the *same set of `[`**square brackets**`]` :

     - I need the 13-digit number that follows `timestampMS`, *and*,
     - the one- to three- digit number that follows `WALKING`.

If it's simpler to include a little more data, like "*all* the timestamps", or "*all* activities", I could easily sift through it later.  **The goal is to make the file small** enough that I can manipulate it without the need to [rent a supercomputer](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/big-data/), lol.

<sup>I tried adapting existing RegEx's but I have a serious issue with both RegEx and musical instruments: doesn't how hard I try, I just *can't wrap my head around it*.  So, this is indeed a "please write code for me" question, but it's just one expression, and I'll pay it forward by writing code for others today!  Thanks...</sup> ☺
.

```
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1515564666086",    ◁― (Don't need this but it won't hurt)
    "latitudeE7" : -6857630899, 
    "longitudeE7" : -1779694452999,
    "activity" : [ {
      "timestampMs" : "1515564665992",  ◁― EXAMPLE: I want only this, and...
      "activity" : [ {
        "type" : "STILL",
        "confidence" : 65
      }, {                                              ↓
        "type" : "TILTING",
        "confidence" : 4
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_RAIL_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 20                               ↓
      }, {
        "type" : "IN_ROAD_VEHICLE",
        "confidence" : 5
      }, {
        "type" : "ON_FOOT",                             ↓
        "confidence" : 3
      }, {
        "type" : "UNKNOWN",
        "confidence" : 3
      }, {
        "type" : "WALKING",             ◁―┬━━ ...AND, I also want this.
        "confidence" : 3                ◁―┘
      } ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "timestampMs" : "1515564662594",    ◁― (Don't need this but it won't hurt)
    "latitudeE7" : -6857630899, 
    "longitudeE7" : -1779694452999,
    "altitude" : 42
  }, {
```

---

### Edit:

For testing purposes I made a sample file, representative of the original (except for the size).  The raw JSON can be loaded directly from [this Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/raw/cDdiH5r2), *or* downloaded as a local copy with [this TinyUpload link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=01279797037503415242&t=0127979703750341524266070), *or* copied as "one long line" below:

```
{"locations" : [ {"timestampMs" : "1515565441334","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 2299}, {"timestampMs" : "1515565288606","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 12,"velocity" : 0,"heading" : 350,"altitude" : 42,"activity" : [ {"timestampMs" : "1515565288515","activity" : [ {"type" : "STILL","confidence" : 98}, {"type" : "ON_FOOT","confidence" : 1}, {"type" : "UNKNOWN","confidence" : 1}, {"type" : "WALKING","confidence" : 1} ]} ]}, {"timestampMs" : "1515565285131","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 12,"velocity" : 0,"heading" : 350,"altitude" : 42}, {"timestampMs" : "1513511490011","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 25,"altitude" : -9,"verticalAccuracy" : 2}, {"timestampMs" : "1513511369962","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 25,"altitude" : -9,"verticalAccuracy" : 2}, {"timestampMs" : "1513511179720","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 16,"altitude" : -12,"verticalAccuracy" : 2}, {"timestampMs" : "1513511059677","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 16,"altitude" : -12,"verticalAccuracy" : 2}, {"timestampMs" : "1513510928842","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 16,"altitude" : -12,"verticalAccuracy" : 2,"activity" : [ {"timestampMs" : "1513510942911","activity" : [ {"type" : "STILL","confidence" : 100} ]} ]}, {"timestampMs" : "1513510913776","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 15,"altitude" : -11,"verticalAccuracy" : 2,"activity" : [ {"timestampMs" : "1513507320258","activity" : [ {"type" : "TILTING","confidence" : 100} ]} ]}, {"timestampMs" : "1513510898735","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 16,"altitude" : -12,"verticalAccuracy" : 2}, {"timestampMs" : "1513510874140","latitudeE7" : 123456789,"longitudeE7" : -123456789,"accuracy" : 19,"altitude" : -12,"verticalAccuracy" : 2,"activity" : [ {"timestampMs" : "1513510874245","activity" : [ {"type" : "STILL","confidence" : 100} ]} ]} ]}
```

The file tested as valid with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and [FreeFormatter](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html).

Comment: It is strange you find it difficult to work with 80MB file in Notepad++. I have issues working with 500MB files there, but 80MB is OK. IMHO, you must focus on solving your main issue, not JSON file "shrinking". JSON parsing tools should work with huge JSON files without any problems.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - We're talking 80 meg's, as in almsot 0.1gb, right?  And a "replace all" function?  Last example was a Replace All `,  \n` with `,\n\r`, on 2 different laptops (Win7, Win10, both 64bit), N++ freezes. I waited 10 minutes then gave up.)  Large files *open* okay-ish, I just can't run a huge operation like that. Is that what you're referring to as the "main issue"?  This particular set of files is a one-time task but I can think of many ways I'l be able to adapt a RegEx like that to other things I'm working on.

Comment: Well, if you only have 1 file for a one-off task, I'd stick to NPP but use it efficiently. If you need to replace `, \n` with `,\n\r`, you need no regex, there is *Extended* mode. If you have more files or there will be similar tasks in future, I'd just write a Python script with customizable options. I would not use VBA. BTW, with Python, it is really easy to parse JSON, just `import json`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - That was a non-RegEx example of something that froze RegEx to the point of having to kill the task, with the same files.  That doesn't solve my problem.  (And it's few enough files I wouldn't mind doing it in NPP - if I could figure out the RegEx for my task - and if RegEx didn't freeze on even a presumably-simpler task.)

Comment: So, is your question a request to teach you write *efficient*  regex patterns? What is the *real* problem? I process 300MB text files with regex in NPP without much trouble. However, I have earned 1/4M rep answering regex SO questions. I also know when to use regex (thanks to this). When you have JSON files, use a JSON parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't write any usable RegEx, I've spent countless hours on [RegExOne](https://regexone.com/), [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) , [Rexegg](http://www.rexegg.com/) etc; it's a handicap.  **End goal**: get all data "between 2nd & 3rd arrows in example" from 40-80mb files, to dump into Access or SQL Server for analysis. I just need one file to process correctly, even if I have to do it one `activity` at a time, then I could automate the repetition. (and as I mentioned, the "magic RegEx' that could accomplish this would also be recycled  for other purposes.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm not asking for a lesson, and (as I mentioned) I realize I shouldn't be asking someone to write code for me (even if it's only 10 characters long!) and I'm giving newbies crap for that constantly... but I'm stuck and hopefully I've earned enough Karma around here to earn me one wee expression.  :)   ...oh and I'm also very curious if there's something specific about Python that makes it handle the files so quickly -- but that's more for curiosity's sake.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/YQot4v/1, it matches the text you asked. it won't work in Python since `re` does not support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: sweet - I'll check it out now on a smaller file.

Comment: @ashleedawg: You have tagged your question with Python, and you're linking to a Python script that seemingly parses this file very quickly, but between the lines I get the impression that you're looking for a solution in VBA? You link to one library and say that it can't handle the throughput. Have you considered [VBA-tools/VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)?

Comment: @SimonShine The [tag:python] tag was an afterthought ("why does Python do it so fast but not VBA?") and just noticed SO moved it to the front.  I don't know Python; I'll delete the tag - it's misleading.  Also I linked to VBA-tools in my question. I find VBA-JSON troublesome & unreliable under *normal* conditions, and nonfunctional with files of this size (but thank you!)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice - thank you...  except it be easily **inverted**, since the goal is to remove everything but the selection?  I would parse through all the matches... except I can't parse the file in VBA.   (although maybe I could figure out where to plug that Regex in the Python file, since it's somehow parsing the file.

Comment: @SimonShine - also to clarify, the Python file parses the file quickly with different criteria, and I'm unable to adjust it.  I included the file as proof of effort made and as a solution to a similar problem.

Comment: That is when usually NPP crashes :)  A kamikaze regex for NPP: see [the regex pattern here](https://regex101.com/r/YQot4v/2) and replace with `(?{1}$1:\n)`.

Comment: @ashleedawg, the implementation of [JSON-Converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) is far from efficient and I doubt that you'll achieve something with a regex. With a 40mb Json, the best you can expect is over 10 seconds with VBA (see [JsonIO](https://gist.github.com/florentbr/12c90342af901b39350eaee6a72bed3d#file-3-jsonio-cls) for more efficient implementation).

Comment: @FlorentB. I was just agreeing with you about VBA-JSON / JSON-Convertor [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671715/reg-expression-to-reduce-huge-file-size-plus?noredirect=1#comment86355545_49671715). It's been a source of much frustration and wasted time for me.  Thanks for the link, I will check out JsonIO in a while though - on an unrelated project that also involves JSON and VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obvious choices ...

The obvious choice here is a JSON-aware tool that can handle large files quickly.  In the following, I'll use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which can easily handle gigabyte-size files quickly so long as there is sufficient RAM to hold the file in memory, and which can also handle very large files even if there is insufficient RAM to hold the JSON in memory.

First, let's assume that the file consists of an array of JSON objects of the form shown, and that the goal is to extract the two values for each admissible sub-object.

This is a jq program that would do the job:

```
.[].activity[]
| .timestampMs as $ts
| .activity[]
| select(.type == "WALKING")
| [$ts, .confidence]
```

For the given input, this would produce:

```
["1515564665992",3]
```

More specifically, assuming the above program is in a file named program.jq and that the input file is input.json, a suitable invocation of jq would be as follows:

```
jq -cf program.jq input.json
```

It should be easy to modify the jq program given above to handle other cases, e.g. if the JSON schema is more complex than has been assumed above.  For example, if there is some irregularity in the schema, try sprinkling in some postfix `?`s, e.g.:

```
.[].activity[]?
| .timestampMs as $ts
| .activity[]?
| select(.type? == "WALKING")
| [$ts, .confidence]
```

Comment: Looks like a promising app - but didn't quite work. JQ1.5/win64 [crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AITy.png) at every attempt (I'm Win7/64bit). JQ1.5/Win32 ran but each file gave an error like: jq: `error (at LocationHistory20180109.json:1734218): Cannot index array with string "activity"` where `1734218` is the 2nd-to-last line of the file.
`jq: error (at LocationHistory20180109.json:1734218): Cannot index array with string "activity"` Last 2 lines: `} ]`  `}`.  A quick fix I assume?  (Can't parse the last occurrence etc?)

Comment: Also I assume you just renamed the executable from jq-win32 or jq-win64 to jq.exe ?

Comment: If the input is invalid JSON, that might indeed be a challenge, but if it's merely irregular, try sprinkling in some ?s as suggested in the update.  If that does not work, maybe you could show the last part of the file, e.g. the last item in the top-level array. (To check whether the input is sufficiently valid JSON, try running: `jq empty input.json`)

Comment: I created a sample file for linking or downloading (I added file links to the bottom of my question.)  This version of the file still give the error in `jq` but validates properly online.  I appreciate your continued effort; I haven't had time to try the other answers yet - they look promising as well - although I do like the sounds of **`jq`** and as a command-line utility, I could also call it programmatically.  (I'm surprised I haven't heard of it before!)

Comment: The pastebin file has the items of interest in `.locations`, so you would obviously have to modify the jq program accordingly (e.g. change the initial `.` to `.locations`).  After doing so, everything works beautifully.

Comment: honest, I've been trying!  When I made the last change you suggested I get `Cannot iterate over null (null)`.  I discovered the online "playground" and I've been experimenting but haven't made it anywhere... Here's the snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/pcTR8mAbW_

Comment: In the jqplay.org snippet, there is not a single "?" in the jq program!  In your example, you only need the first one: https://jqplay.org/s/1oOVOg568I

Comment: I guess I copied the jq before the edit and didn't notice the change... but **thank you**, it works great even on the big ones.  I'll accept your answer.  Last question, I need to get the output into Excel or Access.  Shall I just use `>filename.txt` on the command line with jq or is there a better way?

Comment: I would use `@tsv` and save as a TSV (tab-separated values) file, which Excel (and others) can easily handle.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
(?s)^.*?\"longitude[^\[]*?\"activity[^\[]*\[[^\]]*?timestampMs\"[^\"\]]*\"(\d+)\"[^\]]*WALKING[^\]]*?confidence\"\s*:\s*(\b\d{1,3}\b)[^\]]*?\].*$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/o55aj1/4),,,in which I searched and approached to the target capturing values( `timestamp value, walking value`) through such keywords like  "`longitude`", "`activity`", "`[`", "`timestampMs`", "`]`", "`walking`", "`confidence`".

Python script

```
ss=""" copy & paste the file contents' strings (above sample text) in this area """

regx= re.compile(r"(?s)^.*?\"longitude[^\[]*?\"activity[^\[]*\[[^\]]*?timestampMs\"[^\"\]]*\"(\d+)\"[^\]]*WALKING[^\]]*?confidence\"\s*:\s*(\b\d{1,3}\b)[^\]]*?\].*$")

matching= regx.match(ss)    # method 1 : using match() function's capturing group
timestamp= matching.group(1)
walkingval= matching.group(2)
print("\ntimestamp is %s\nwalking value is %s" %(timestamp,walkingval))

print("\n"+regx.sub(r'\1 \2',ss))    # another method by using sub() function
```

Output is

```
timestamp is 1515564665992
walking value is 3

1515564665992 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems you've picked a language without a performant JSON parser.

With Python you could have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import json

def get_history(filename):
    with open(filename) as history_file:
        return json.load(history_file)

def walking_confidence(history):
    for location in history["locations"]:
        if "activity" not in location:
            continue

        for outer_activity in location["activity"]:
            confidence = extract_walking_confidence(outer_activity)
            if confidence:
                timestampMs = int(outer_activity["timestampMs"])
                yield (timestampMs, confidence)

def extract_walking_confidence(outer_activity):
    for inner_activity in outer_activity["activity"]:
        if inner_activity["type"] == "WALKING":
            return inner_activity["confidence"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.clock()
    history = get_history("history.json")

    middle = time.clock()
    wcs = list(walking_confidence(history))

    end = time.clock()
    print("load json: " + str(middle - start) + "s")
    print("loop json: " + str(end - middle) + "s")
```

On my 98MB JSON history this prints:

> load json: 3.10292s
>   loop json: 0.338841s

That isn't terribly performant, but certainly not bad.